# How to create Hierarchial table in sql columnwise using joins and handling circular relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a hierarchy table using parent child dataset like this with output as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Now I have written the code like this to get all the levels (refer screenshot):

[image]

```
select a1."Parent_id" as level1 ,
a1."Child_id" as level2,
a2."Child_id" as level3,
a3."Child_id" as level4,
a4."Child_id" as level5
from "ParentChildHierarchy"."Hierarchy" as a1
left join "ParentChildHierarchy"."Hierarchy" as a2 on a1."Child_id" = a2."Parent_id"
left join "ParentChildHierarchy"."Hierarchy" as a3 on a2."Child_id" = a3."Parent_id"
left join "ParentChildHierarchy"."Hierarchy" as a4 on a3."Child_id" = a4."Parent_id"
where a1."Parent_id" in (select a1."Parent_id" 
    from "ParentChildHierarchy"."Hierarchy" a1
    where a1."Child_id" in (a1."Parent_id")) 
and 
(a1."Parent_id"<>a1."Child_id")
order by level3,level2,level1
```

but I am unable to handle the circular relationship which is causing repetition like in row 8 and 10.
And I am getting the output as below:

[image]

```
"A" "B""C"  "D1"    
"A" "B" "C" "D2"    
"A" "B" "C1"        
"A" "B" "C2"        
"A" "B1""C3"        
"A" "B1""C4"        
"E" "F" "G" "H1"    
"E" "F" "G" "F" "G1"
"E" "F" "G" "H" 
"E" "F" "G" "F" "G"
"E" "F" "G1"        
"P" "Q" "R1"        
"P" "Q1""R1"        
"P" "Q" "R2"        
"P" "Q1""R3"        
"E" "F1"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to handle the circular relationship" - are you trying to stop circular relationships being created or are you trying to query circular references? If you are trying to query it then what do you want the result to be when there's a circular reference? Also, is there a maximum depth to any hierarchy or it it effectively unlimited?

Comment: I want to stop the circular relationship being created. like in this output row "E" "F" "G" "F" "G" it should not repeat.

Comment: You would have to build the logic into some sort of process that controls the INSERT/UPDATE e.g. in a Stored Procedure. There’s no way of building this logic into a simple INSERT statement